# Does apostrophe-soundcloud work for Apostrophe CMS 2.0?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm looking to include SoundCloud to our website. does the apostrophe-SoundCloud module still work for Apostrophe CMS 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

No, the `apostrophe-soundcloud` module has not been ported to 2.0 We'd welcome a PR a on an update.

Alternatively, you can embed Soundcloud players in `apostrophe-html-widgets` by using their official HTML embed.

https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed